# Reuse generic types of extended interface when creating a shorthand type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a shorthand type for my actions that work with  [`AsyncActionCreators`](https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa/blob/master/src/index.ts#L92) objects.

I've created a simple function which takes a React `dispatch: Dispatch<T>` parameter:

```
const fetchProfileAction = actionCreator.async<void, Profile, any>('FETCH_PROFILE');
// AsyncActionCreators<Params = void, Result = Profile, Error = any>;


type AsyncDispatch<A extends AsyncActionCreators<Params, Result, Error>, Params, Result, Error> = Dispatch<
  ReturnType<A['started'] | A['done'] | A['failed']>
>;

export const fetchProfile = (
  dispatch: AsyncDispatch<typeof fetchProfileAction, void, Profile, any>,
) => async () => {
  dispatch(fetchProfileAction.started());

  try {
    dispatch(fetchProfileAction.done({ result: (await api.get<Profile>('/profile')).data }));
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch(fetchProfileAction.failed(e));
  }
};
```

The problem for now is that I have to specify manually the types used within `fetchProfileAction`:

```
AsyncDispatch<typeof fetchProfileAction, void, Profile, any>
```

Is it possible to simplify that and end up with something like `AsyncDispatch<typeof fetchProfileAction>` with autimatically resolved `Params`, `Result`, `Error` types of `AsyncActionCreators`?

Comment: Didn't tested this, but you can try and use conditional types (sorry for formatting in comments): `type AsyncDispatch<A> = A extends AsyncActionCreators<infer Params, infer Result, infer Error>
    ? Dispatch<ReturnType<A['started'] | A['done'] | A['failed']>>
    : never;`

Comment: @AlekseyL. `infer` did the trick! If you'll post it as an aswer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type AsyncDispatch<A> = A extends AsyncActionCreators<infer Params, infer Result, infer Error>
    ? Dispatch<ReturnType<A['started'] | A['done'] | A['failed']>>
    : never;
```